# HTML Agility Pack HtmlDocument Show All Html?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I am using the following to get a web page which works fine

```
    public static HtmlDocument GetWebPageFromUrl(string url)
    {
        var hw = new HtmlWeb();
        return hw.Load(url);
    }
```

But how to I spit the entire contents of the HTML out from the HtmlDocument into a string?

I tried HtmlDocument.ToString() but that doesn't give me all the HTML in the document? Any ideas?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`DocumentNode.OuterHtml` contains the full html:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("sample.html");
string html = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

In your example:

```
public static string GetWebPageHtmlFromUrl(string url)
{
    var hw = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(url);
    return doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
}
```

Comment: +1, as I have not understand the question and did not answer properly and deleted my answer.