# Optimized Algorithm to compare Templates of two URLs

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, templates, jsoup

**EDITED, Please Read Again, As I added some work of mine**

My task is to compare templates of two URLS. I am ready with my algorithm. But it takes too much time to give final answer.

I wrote my code in *Java* using *Jsoup* and *Selenium*

Here, *Templates* means the way any page presents its contents.

**Example:-**

Any shopping website have page of any Shoes, that contains,

```
Images in the left.
Price and Size in the right.
Reviews in the bottom.
```

If two URLS are of any specific product , then it return "Both are from same templates". Example , [this link](http://www.jabong.com/Lara-Karen-Full-Sleeve-Black-Polyester-Top-With-Cotton-Lace-196636.html) and [this link](http://www.jabong.com/Puma-Flash-Ind-Black-Running-Shoes-187831.html) have same template.

If one URL shows any product and another URL shows any category ,then it shows "No match".
Example, [this link](http://www.jabong.com/Lara-Karen-Full-Sleeve-Black-Polyester-Top-With-Cotton-Lace-196636.html) and [this link](http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/womens-tops/) are from different template.

I think that this algorithm requires some optimization, that's why I am posting this question in this forum.

**My algorithm**

1. Fetch, parse two input URLS and make their [DOM trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).
2. Then if any page contains , UL and TABLE , then remove that tag. I done this because, may be two pages contains different number of items.
3. Then, I count number of tags in both URLS. say, initial_tag1, initial_tag2.
4. Then, I start removing tags that have same position on corresponding pages and same Id and their below subtree, if that tree has number of nodes less than 10.
5. Then, I start removing tags that have same position on coresponding pages and same Class name and their below subtree, if that tree has number of nodes less than 10..
6. Then, I start removing tags that have no Id ,and No Class name and their below subtree, if that tree has number of nodes less than 10.
7. Steps 4, 5, 6 have (N*N) complexity. Here, N, is number of tags. [In this way, in every step DOM tree going to shrink]
8. When it comes out from this recursion, then I check final_tag1 and final_tag2.
9. If final_tag1 and final_tag2 is less than initial_tag1*(0.2) and initial_tag2*(0.2) then I **can** say that `Two URL matched`, otherwise `not`.

I think a lot about this algorithm, and I found that removing node from DOM tree is pretty slow process. This may be the culprit for slowing this algorithm.

I discussed from some of geeks, and

> they said that use a score for every tag instead of removing them, and add them , and > at the end return (score I Got)/(accumulatedPoints) or something similar, and on the 
>   basis of that you decide two URLS are either similar or not.

But I didn't understand this. So can you explain this saying of some geek, or can you give any other optimized algorithm, that solve this problem efficiently.

Thanks in advance. Looking for your kind response.

Comment: This is an unusual thing to want to do. I think you will be very lucky to find anyone with experience in what one might term "derived template comparison". When you have cracked it, you will be the expert.

Comment: Are you looking on Styles, too? Or only on the structure of the DOM-tree?

Comment: Sounds like a non-trivial problem to me generally, I'm curious: apart from the time requirements, does your algorithm work as well as you want it to?

Comment: A thought: whatever algorithm you use for comparison, avoid having to repeatedly enquire/manipulate the DOM by initially mapping the two DOMs into javascript (eg with jQuery("*")).

Comment: @StefanNeubert Only on the structure of DOM-tree.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Then what can I use. Everytime I have to make a new list. Help me by giving any solution that do all the things intelligently.

Comment: I suspect you'll have trouble if you're doing this with a DOM. Deleting items in the DOM is not exactly fast. You'll need to use a stream-style HTML parser and some pretty involved merge logic if you want to do this quickly.

Comment: @JimMischel Can you please elaborate your last line. I didn't get that. Please explain that in a simpler way.

Comment: @JimMischel http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/net/htmlparser/jericho/StreamedSource.html Is this link is good to implement stream style parsing?  Is language makes any effect on speed (JAVA / JAVASCRIPT)?

Comment: @jhamb, I already made a suggestion - map the two DOMs into javascript. Then do as much as possible wholly in javascript - interact with the DOMs as little as possible. You may already do this - I only know as much as you posted in the question.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I already made my code in JS, but that code makes list of all tags, then remove same tags, then again makes list of all tags. Algorithm continue this process, until it gets terminate condition. But this makes its speed very slow. But mapping concept, that you said, I didn't understand. Can you give me some more hint, so that I can implement that also.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is similar to what you are already doing. Stop thinking in terms of "tags" and start thinking in terms of "nodes". When a node needs to be removed, then remove it from the javascript mapping of the DOM. That way you win two ways - (1) by not having to remove items from the DOM (which is slow), and (2) by not having to continually recreate the list (which is also slow). It's just a slight change of mindset and probably involves only minor changes to the code. The main thing is that your overall approach (your algorithm) need not change in order to get better performance.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot But one thing that I didn't understand is node is similar to tag, then how can it be helpful var. I made list of tags by using this call `tag_list = doc1.getElementsByTagName(tag);`

Comment: "Tag" is an HTML term. When a web page loads, HTML is interpreted and DOM nodes created. The tags that formed the original HTML have done their job. When a jQuery selector interacts with the DOM, it makes an array-like object containing zero or more references to DOM nodes. If you execute the jQuery `.html()` command, the string it returns is totally synthetic HTML recreated from the DOM; not the original HTML from which the DOM was constructed. What you are trying to do is complex and ambitious. You have to get your mind round the basics before you can do the tricky stuff efficiently.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot One thing I didn't understand, ultimately our target is to prune DOM tree by removing similar element and their children. So where I am wrong in my approach. Is their any fast method for parsing HTML in JQuery. May be by doing so, it speed up the performance, or their is any method so that I can make up the DOM tree, as n-tree data structure. Then I can check every element in another TREE. In this way , the complexity become O(N*N*LogN). AM I right ? Help me by giving some suggestion.

Comment: @jhamb, I have described my recommended approach to the best of my ability. All I can do now is refer you back to my earlier explanations.

Comment: Why don't you just compare the two pages node-by-node, recursing their DOM trees respectively? Btw, "position in a (DOM) tree" and "by id" do not have quadratic complexity.

Comment: @Bergi But I didn't understand, how can I compare two DOM tree node-by-node. Give some implementation clue. PLease

Comment: `function compare(node1, node2) { if (node1 like node2) for (i from 0 to children.length) compare(node1.children[i], node2.children[i]) }`. You might want to measure alikeness and aggregate it while recursing or something.

Comment: @All Please read above question, as I added some of my work.

Comment: @All Help me  I have one doubt, If I remove position calculation part, and I say if two tags have same id and same class name, then both must be at same position in theri respective pages. Is it assumption is correct or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve complexity of your algorithm, supposing you are using Jsoup, you must adapt your data structure to your algorithm.

4) What do you mean by position of tag ? the Xpath of the tag ?
If yes, precompute this value once for each tag O(n) and store this value in each node. If required you can also store it in a HashMap to retrieve in O(1).

5) Index you tag by class name using MultiMap. You will save lot of computation

6) Index class with no Id, no class name

All these pre computations can be performed in one traversal of the tree so O(n).

Generally if you want to reduce computation, you will have to store more data in the memory. Since DOM page are very small data, this is no problem in your case.

Comment: Thanks, I think this post is helpful for me. First point, see Edit no. 1 for your first point in your answer. Second point, my code is in Javascript, Jquery, HTML. Can I follow all your instructions in JS, or I have to shift my code in Java? Third point, can you know the similar `closest function` of Jquery in Java? Forth point, how can I retreive position in O(1) time, what is the key that you made for searching , tag , tag id or tag class name ? Fifth point, Can you give some code outline for your `4) point`, code to store position of tag in node ?

Comment: If you don't need to use Javascript (i.e. code running in Browser), avoid JS when you need performance. It is monothreaded, slow as hell, and awful to debug. Instead use Java, it has very powerful collections frameworks (the one in the JDK, Guava ...). And finally do not forget to upvote answers ;)

Comment: I up-voted both your answers, as you took time for me, and your answer also helps me. But, tell me one thing, Is it good to shift my code in Java ? If you have time than can we chat for few minutes, please.

Comment: I am unable to get the position of tags in Java. Help me please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740533/code-to-find-absolute-position-of-an-element-of-dom-in-java
I am unable to find `closest` function in java 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741415/how-to-know-any-element-is-in-dom-or-not-in-java-using-jsoup.

Comment: Sure I just created a room with your name

Comment: I try to use `selenium` in maven , as you said in our last discussion. But it shows some error. 
I posted that error  here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744732/java-code-throws-exception-after-adding-selenium-java-2-31-0-library-in-netbeans

Comment: See above link, as we discuss on chat about Selenium, but it didn't work. Please help me in working that. Please.

Comment: Please read above question, I added some discussion with one geek, but that is totally bounces me. So please give me some method, after reading above question, please.

Comment: Help me  I have one doubt, If I remove position calculation part, and I say if two tags have same id and same class name, then both must be at same position in theri respective pages. Is it assumption is correct or not ?

Answer (score 2):

For comparing webpages there basically two ways, the fast and the slow one :

1. Compare URLS : fast
2. Compare DOM : slow (and complicated)

In your case, it appears that the first two items match a similar regular expression and the categories match another regexp.

Here is a short JAVA solution

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestRegexp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String URL_ITEM_1 = "http://www.jabong.com/Puma-Flash-Ind-Black-Running-Shoes-187831.html";
    String URL_ITEM_2 = "http://www.jabong.com/Lara-Karen-Full-Sleeve-Black-Polyester-Top-With-Cotton-Lace-196636.html";
    String URL_CATEGORY_1 = "http://www.jabong.com/kids/shoes/floaters/";
    String URL_CATEGORY_2 = "http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/womens-tops/";

    Pattern itemPattern = Pattern.compile("http://www\\.jabong.com/([\\w\\p{Punct}\\d]+)\\.html");
    Pattern categoryPattern = Pattern.compile("http://www\\.jabong.com/([\\w\\p{Punct}]+/)+");

    System.out.println("Matching items");
    Matcher matcher = itemPattern.matcher(URL_ITEM_1);
    System.out.println(matcher.matches());
    matcher = itemPattern.matcher(URL_ITEM_2);
    System.out.println(matcher.matches());
    matcher = itemPattern.matcher(URL_CATEGORY_1);
    System.out.println(matcher.matches());
    matcher = itemPattern.matcher(URL_CATEGORY_2);
    System.out.println(matcher.matches());

    System.out.println("Matching categories");
    Matcher category = categoryPattern.matcher(URL_ITEM_1);
    System.out.println(category.matches());
    category = categoryPattern.matcher(URL_ITEM_2);
    System.out.println(category.matches());
    category = categoryPattern.matcher(URL_CATEGORY_1);
    System.out.println(category.matches());
    category = categoryPattern.matcher(URL_CATEGORY_2);
    System.out.println(category.matches());
}
}
```

And the output :

```
Matching items
true
true
false
false
Matching categories
false
false
true
true
```

It validates the first two first URLS as being items, the two last as being categories.

I hope it matches your requirement. Feel free to adapt in JS.

Comment: First of all thanks for this code. But this code logic is not upto my requirement. If two items from different sites i.e., Jabong and Amazon, then ?
How can it make comparison of two templates?

Comment: Can you give any code for DOM TREE comparison, then that will be very helpful for me.

Comment: In fact for your problem, DOM manipulation is of no interest, since you want to analyze the template, which is the result of DOM + CSS rendered by the browser. 

You should process some image analysis on the rendered page, that would be meaningful compared to only DOM processing.

Hint : this is not as simple as it may seem to be

Comment: Yes I know, it is not so simple. But I have to code this, and yes, I am ready with my protocol. But that is naive approach. Now, I want to optimize that. Give me some way to do that.
Tell me one thing, how can I iterate DOM tree as binary tree. I think that help me, because by using that I can find that in O(n*n*Log(n)) time complexity.

Comment: http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/womens-tops/?apw_size=10 How can I check this link using regular expression. How can I extract website name, just like , extract "Jabong" from above. As I am not good in regular expression. So, help me in that.

Comment: But everytime Product item is not ending with .html, check these,  http://www.flipkart.com/united-colors-benetton-checkered-casual-men-s-shirt/p/itmdhx3dxastzfp5?pid=SHTDHWRCMX8UZHMV&ref=c5c59d68-7301-4a17-8f0c-6665d3633c76, http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1594205124/ref=s9_al_bw_g14_ir02?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-3&pf_rd_r=3714E536A1A9474DA15A&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1501255222&pf_rd_i=390919011, http://www.myntra.com/Shirts/United-Colors-of-Benetton/United-Colors-of-Benetton-Men-Navy-Blue-Shirt/109006/buy?nav_id=7&searchQuery=men-casual-shirts&serp=1&uq=false# .

Comment: Then your above is not successful everytime. It i true only for some websites.