# Code to find absolute position of an element of DOM in Java

Tags: java, javascript, dom, coordinates, jsoup

I am working on a project in **Java**.

In this project, I have to find  absolute position of an element of DOM. But I don't know how to do this.

I searched on net, I found the same for Javascript. I found this from [here](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/get_element_position_using_javascript.htm).

**Code is this**,

```
function getPosition(element) {
    var xPosition = 0;
    var yPosition = 0;

    while(element) {
        xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
        yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
        element = element.offsetParent;
    }
    return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
}
```

When I try to write this code in Java, **offsetLeft, offsetTop** variable is not found. Can you tell me, how can I write this code in Java?

**Edit No. 1**

Is there any method using **Jsoup** for the same?

Comment: Where will your Java code run? Server-side, where it's authoring the HTML? Client-side, in a Java applet? Also, what do you plan to do with the element's absolute position? What's the greater goal you're trying to accomplish? There may be a simpler/more direct way to accomplish it.

Comment: @miorel Your all questions answer in my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718235/optimized-algorithm-to-compare-templates-of-two-urls

Comment: @miorel I get URL DOM tree by using `Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect(url1).get();`

Answer (score 0):

There are only two methods giving you a position in Jsoup:

- [Element.elementSiblingIndex()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#elementSiblingIndex%28%29)
- [Node.siblingIndex()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#siblingIndex%28%29)

(you can get the count of childs too)

But there's no `offsetLeft` or `offsetTop` in Jsoup

Comment: `I.e. if this is the first element sibling, returns 0.`. What this means ?
Is this method returns the absolute position of this element?

Comment: i don't think so. you'll get the position (order) of the sibling, not the absolut index. so `0` is the first *sibling*, not the first element.