# Java code throws exception after adding Selenium-java-2.31.0 library in Maven

Tags: java, exception, maven-3, selenium-webdriver

I am working on Netbeans. I added a library selenium-java-2.31.0. But it shows exception.
I added all the libraries on which this library is dependent.

I follow this [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/2.31.0) to add library in netbeans.

**My code :-**

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        String url1 = "http://www.jabong.com/giordano-P6868-Black-Analog-Watch-183702.html";


        Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect(url1).get();

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(url1);  


        Elements tag_list = doc1.getAllElements();

        for( Element tag1 : tag_list ) {
            Point point=driver.findElement(By.id(tag1.id())).getLocation();  
            System.out.println("X Position : " + point.x);  
            System.out.println("Y Position : " + point.y);

        }
}
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at template_matching.Template_matching.main(Template_matching.java:275)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 1 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Help me in solving this problem. Why this exception throws?

**Edit No. 1**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.<init>(FirefoxProfile.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.<init>(FirefoxProfile.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.<init>(FirefoxProfile.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.getProfile(FirefoxDriver.java:260)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:179)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:92)
    at template_matching.Template_matching.main(Template_matching.java:275)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 11 more
Java Result: 1
```

**Edit no.2**

Now I moved to maven, by thinking it downloads all the dependent libraries. But now it shows diffrerent error.

[image]

**Edit No. 3**

As it shows some problem with firefox, I replaced firefox with Chrome. 
This time previous error is removed. But a new comes in picture. Please see this.

[image]

**Edit no. 4**

[image]

**Edit No. 5**

Now I shifted to firefox again, and gets given page, but it stucks then. Why ?

Below is the error snapshot that I got.

[image]

Comment: You need [`Google Guava`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) in your classpath by the looks of things. This is where the class `com.google.common.base.Function` lives.

Comment: @bmorris591 Now it shows new Exception. See edit No. 1.

Comment: Another missing class, this time `org.json.JSONException`. Google it and see where it comes from.

Comment: @bmorris591 I shifted to maven. See Edit No. 2. But it shows some different errors. It opens firefox, and stops there. I don't understand why it happens.

Comment: This looks like an error from Firefox, look at the text ("NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI") - it seems fairly clear.

Comment: @bmorris591 What can I do now ? Do you have any solution to overcome from this ?

Comment: @bmorris591 Please see Edit no. 3. As I replace firefox with chrome. It shows another error. Please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem you are seeing at this point is due to you passing in driver.get("url1");

I think you mean to be passing in driver.get(url1); (Notice no quotation marks)

To expand on it a little bit, the reason it is throwing the malformed uri exception is that the uri being passed in (url1) does not contain any protocol (http/https).

Comment: Thanks for your nice observation. But it shows again some exception. See edit no. 4, please.

Comment: I also added `chrome.exe` absolute path in path variable.

Comment: I dont see alot about how you have chromedriver set up in your project. Having set it up before my first question would be have you downloaded and installed the server file? I would go through the instructions here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver and after having followed them see if you still get the exception. Chromedriver is a bit different than firefox in that it requires more than one file for it to actually be used. The browser itself and the server, and the server must also be in path.

Comment: I shifted back to firefox. But that problem solves, and a new arises. Please me in solving this. Please.

Comment: Your new problem looks as though it may be a jsoup implementation issue. It looks like the id that it is trying to find is just "". I am not familiar with jsoup but i think if you were to do a simple driver.findElement(By.id("place known id here")); you would not get this exception. And to make your test a bit more robust I would suggest accessing most of your webelements through waits as well such as wait.until(ExceptedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocaed(By.id(known id here))); This will more accurately mimic an actual users page interaction.

Comment: Yes, in my case, there may be a chance that `id` is `null`.
Actually, what I try to do is, process all the `tags` in `DOM` and store their respective `positions`.
So that I can optimize my given code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718235/optimized-algorithm-to-compare-templates-of-two-urls

Comment: How can I perform this task, now I replaced that Id with a specific "ID". But again it stucks. Why ?

Comment: I think it kind of goes back to your jsoup implementation which I am not familiar with. You may have more luck if you throw Point point=driver.findElement(By.id(tag1.id())).getLocation(); in a try catch so that it will not immediately break if it failes to find an element with a null id or other locator.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have created a maven project which will solve your dependency problem related to the selenium.

Comment: I am already working in maven. Please see Edit no. 5, it shows my original problem.