# How to get dynamic contents of any web page in DOM tree using JSOUP in Java

Tags: java, html, algorithm, dom, jsoup

In my project, which parses the HTML page, then uses the DOM tree for different operations, just like, comparing templates of two URLS.

For that, I am using **JSOUP**.

But it does not able to load Dynamic contents in DOM tree.

Can you tell me how can I load dynamic content using JSOUP in Java, or can you tell me any other method for doing the same?

**EDIT NO. 1**

As [given link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625043/getting-jsoup-to-support-dynamically-generated-html-by-javascript) shows, it works using **PhantomJS** and **Zombie.js** in Java. Can you tell me how can I do this ?

**Edit No. 2**

I first try to get dynamic page by using Selenium, and the code is as follows,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

 // Selenium
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.get("ANY URL HERE");  
 String html_content = driver.getPageSource();
 driver.get("ANOTHER URL HERE");
 String html_content1 = driver.getPageSource();
 driver.close();

 // Jsoup makes DOM here by parsing HTML content
 Document doc1 = Jsoup.parse(html_content);
 Document doc2 = Jsoup.parse(html_content1);

 // OPERATIONS USING DOM TREE
}
```

But this takes lots of time after optimizing also. Now as per your instructions, I moved to HtmlUnit. 
But I am not able to make code, that gets Dynamic Page source code into String , and then I use this String for further paring using Jsoup, help me to write that code using HtmlUnit.

*Code using HtmlUnit* :-

```
package XXX.YYY.ZZZ.Template_Matching;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 *
 * @author jhamb
 */
public class HtmlUnit {

    @Test
    public void homePage() throws Exception {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.jabong.com/Yepme-3-4Th-Sleeve-Printed-Blue-Top-Mksp-191481.html");

        Document ht = page.getOwnerDocument();
        System.out.println(ht);

        webClient.closeAllWindows();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HtmlUnit htmlUnit = new  HtmlUnit();
        htmlUnit.homePage();
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you fix this? could you get what you want

Comment: To get dynamic content, I used Selenium, and GhostDriver.

Comment: Yes, I completed that project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, JSoup won't work in this case.

Try using HtmlUnit.

Comment: Is HtmlUnit equally eficient as Jsoup is, for parsing and makind DOM tree? Is HTMLUnit contains all methods as Jsoup contains?
Can we do the same work with Jsoup + Selenium ?

Comment: See above Edit No. 1 for my given task.

Comment: Can you tell me the implementation guide, please. I don't know how to start with HtmlUnit, how this helpful in getting dynamic contents.

Comment: Link for the getting started guide: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html

Comment: Hey used this using Selenium,but it takes 95 % of the time of whole processing time. Is HtmlUnit faster than Selenium?
See my question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830334/selenium-tooks-lots-of-the-time-to-get-dynamic-page-of-given-url

Comment: I'd guess that HTMLUnit would be faster.

Comment: Please see Edit No. 2. Please help me in getting dynamic page source in a string for further parsing using Jsoup. Help me in that. Please.