# Selenium takes lots of time to get dynamic page of given URL

Tags: java, dom, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jsoup

I am doing a Project in *Java*.
In this project I have to work with DOM.
For that I first load a dynamic page of any given URL, by using Selenium.
Then I parse them using Jsoup.

**I want to get the dynamic page source code of given URL**

**Code snapshot:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     // Selenium
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.get("ANY URL HERE");  
     String html_content = driver.getPageSource();
     driver.close();

     // Jsoup makes DOM here by parsing HTML content
     Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html_content);

     // OPERATIONS USING DOM TREE
}
```

But the problem is, Selenium takes around 95% of the whole processing time, that is undesirable.

Selenium first opens Firefox, then loads the given page, then gets the dynamic page source code.

Can you tell me how I can reduce the time taken by Selenium, by replacing this tool with another efficient tool. Any other advice would also be welcome.

**Edit NO. 1**

There is some code given on this [link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/TipsAndTricks).

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", "some UA string");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

But what is second line here, I didn't understand. As Documentation is also very poor of selenium.

**Edit No. 2**

System.out.println("Fetching %s..." + url1);
        System.out.println("Fetching %s..." + url2);

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(createFirefoxProfile());

    driver.get("url1");  
    String hml1 = driver.getPageSource();

    driver.get("url2");
    String hml2 = driver.getPageSource();
    driver.close();

    Document doc1 = Jsoup.parse(hml1);
    Document doc2 = Jsoup.parse(hml2);
```

Comment: Try creating a firefox profile and use it with the driver.

Comment: @KDM Can you elaborate this, as I am naive in this field. Please explain this.

Comment: When you create a webdriver using `new FirefoxDriver()` - selenium creates a new profile for firefox and creates it. That itself is a costly operation. You can send a FirefoxProfile object to the constructor, which avoids the creating a new profile each and every time. I will try to put together some code.

Comment: @KDM I added Edit no. 1 , please see that. That shows some code. But that is not  in my range. So please explain this how can I ddo this.

Comment: I added an answer. See whether it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Selenium
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(createFirefoxProfile());
    driver.get("ANY URL HERE");
    String html_content = driver.getPageSource();
    driver.close();

    // Jsoup makes DOM here by parsing HTML content
    // OPERATIONS USING DOM TREE
}

private static FirefoxProfile createFirefoxProfile() {
    File profileDir = new File("/tmp/firefox-profile-dir");
    if (profileDir.exists())
        return new FirefoxProfile(profileDir);
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    File dir = firefoxProfile.layoutOnDisk();
    try {
        profileDir.mkdirs();
        FileUtils.copyDirectory(dir, profileDir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return firefoxProfile;
}
```

The createFireFoxProfile() method creates a profile if one doesn't exist. It uses if a profile already exists. So selenium doesn't need to create the profile-dir structure each and every time.

Comment: THanks, wait I will put this module and check how it effects my project.

Comment: `FileUtils.copyDirectory(dir, profileDir);`. Netbeans says create class FileUtils. I think there is some mistake. Please see.

Comment: It is from apache commons. Selenium also uses it - so add the jar to your project.

Comment: I added this dependency `<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
 <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>`. But it throws the same error.

Comment: I am on eclipse. The JAR I added is commons-io-2.2.jar.

Comment: Yes, it worked on Netbeans also. But in maven it shows error.

Comment: Can you tell me what this function is helpful in my case?

Comment: Time it and see whether it helps. When you create a firefox driver - selenium creates a new profile for the firefox instance. Each time when you create a webdriver, the profile is recreated. This function avoids creating a firefox profile each and every time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying to run this on maven. If I find any problem, I will inform you. Thanks again.

Comment: Now it works on maven also. In my algorithm I have to open two URLS. It performs fine, I first get first URL, then get another URLS.
It becomes faster than previous one. Can it become more efficient ?
See my code in Edit No. 2.

Comment: I perform all the instructions of yours. I observe that it takes around `13 - 18 seconds` to get two URL Page source code(dynamic code). But I want this task to perform in around 1 - 2 seconds or any efficient time. How can I get dynamic pages of two URLS in efficient time? 
Please see my main problem, and this question is the part to make that algorithm efficient. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718235/optimized-algorithm-to-compare-templates-of-two-urls

Comment: If you have few time, then can we discuss my problem via chat, please.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27644/discussion-between-kdm-and-jhamb)

Comment: Can we discuss on chat, please. I need your expert advice. Please give some time.

Comment: I want to apply HtmlUnit for getting dynamic page source code, because Selenium takes around 13 - 18 seconds to get two URLS page source code. I tried to write code using HtmlUnit, but it is not working. Do you know any good tutorial for the same or help me in writing code, please Give some guidence.

Comment: I followed your instructions, and perform the same thing using GhostDriver + PhantomJs, but there is not much difference in the time occurs. What can I do now. Here is my code, that have one error, please see the code. – http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852687/why-code-not-exits-at-the-end-after-closing-the-driver-ghostdriver-phantomjs

Comment: I am ready with my code, and it ran fine for two urls, but when I test the same for the numbers of urls, it fails, Can you please help me ? The question link is  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075837/shows-exception-in-java-code-selenium-jsoup

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure, confident about your code, you can go with phantomjs. it is a headless browser and will get your results with quick hits. FF will take time to execute.

Comment: this late answer may be of short usage. One of the comment of devnull on 6 april 2013 was: "I followed your instructions, and perform the same thing using GhostDriver + PhantomJs, but there is not much difference in the time occurs"