# C# Trying to remove text from rss feed

Tags: c#, rss, windows-runtime, feed

Currently is have this code:

```
        if (caseStudyImages.SelectedIndex < 0)
        {
            caseStudyImages.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        var item = container.Items[caseStudyImages.SelectedIndex];
        subTitle.Text = item.Title.Text;

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(item.NodeValue);

        doc.DocumentNode.RemoveChild(doc.DocumentNode.FirstChild);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            doc.Save(writer);
        }

        item.NodeValue = doc.ToString();       

        caseStudyImages.ItemsSource = container.Items;
```

caseStudyImages is a flipview on the screen that contains an image and a webview item. Container is my syndication feed item. I am trying to remove the first node from the item currently selected, as it is text I do not want, and then display it in the webview. I am binding the webview content the the item.NodeValue in a DataTemplate. My problem is on the line: 
     item.NodeValue = doc.ToString();
I get an exception throw saying "The method or operation is not implemented". Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Either the setter of `item.NodeValue` or `doc.ToString()` is not implemented. What does the StackTrace say where the exception occurs?

Comment: hmmm.. perhaps you want `doc.OuterHtml` or `doc.InnerHtml` instead of `doc.ToString()`?

Comment: > UICentricWin8App.exe!UICentricWin8App.HubPage.LoadText() Line 140 + 0x2c bytes C#
  UICentricWin8App.exe!UICentricWin8App.HubPage.caseStudyImages_SelectionChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e) Line 151 + 0x8 bytes C#
  [External Code] 
  UICentricWin8App.exe!UICentricWin8App.HubPage.LoadImages() Line 83 + 0x49 bytes C#
  UICentricWin8App.exe!UICentricWin8App.HubPage.HubPage_Loaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e) Line 41 + 0xc bytes C#
  [External Code] 
is what is said in call stack

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to HtmlDocument class ? 
Check the ToString ovveride maybe someone left NotImplementedException there.

If you don't have access, then get the needed data from HtmlDocument that is considered to be NodeValue without using ToString(). Use String.Format

Comment: I checked the HtmlDocument class, and theres no override for the ToString method. Should I be using doc to get the text from or sb?

Comment: HtmlDocument is from HtmlAgilityPack ? If so Check this post

Comment: Which post are you talking about?

Comment: oops no link was added in the comment : sending again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599012/html-agility-pack-htmldocument-show-all-html

Comment: Also @Botz3000 sugested to check setter of NodeValue. What type of object is the item ?

Comment: item.NodeValue is a string. It is the text content of the item that it has. I tried using doc.documentnode.outerhtml but it still gives the same error

Comment: Ok, check if you are able to set NodeValue by setter directly. Mayber there is some kind of a function that should be used to set this value. Baacuse as @Botz3000 sugestem there can be a problem with setter of this property.