# C# html viewing using html agility pack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I made a console c# application which is supposed to display the html source of a page.

Instead, the console app is showing `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument`.

Can anyone explain to me why that is?

```
class Program
{
    public HtmlDocument read()
    {
        HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
        try
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = htmlWeb.Load("http://www.yahoo.com");
            return document;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error : " + e.ToString());
            return null;     
        }
    }     

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program dis = new Program();
        string text = Convert.ToString(dis.read());
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.ReadLine();        
    }
}
```

Comment: The output is  "HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument"

Comment: I don't know the model of HtmlDocument; but clearly its ToString() is not implemented to return the html. You will need to inspect the properties and use one of them which should contain the source.

Comment: posisble duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599012/html-agility-pack-htmldocument-show-all-html

Comment: how do I then convert document to string?

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
 return document;
```

with:

```
 return document.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

or if you wanna to extract text only (without HTML tags):

```
 return document.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

the whole code would be:

```
class Program
{
    public string read()
    {
        HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
        try
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = htmlWeb.Load("http://www.yahoo.com");
            return document.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error : " + e.ToString());
            return null;     
        }
    }     

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program dis = new Program();
        string text = dis.read();
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.ReadLine();        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The default implementation of `.ToString()` is just to output the name of the class, which is what you're seeing. So `HtmlDocument` from the HtmlAgilityPack obviously doesn't provide a derived implementation.

From glancing at the [code over on CodePlex](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Trunk/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlDocument.cs), it looks like you need to use the `Save` function to save the output to an `XmlWriter` and then use that to get the string. I don't see another way to get at the whole contents of the page directly from that object (though admittedly I just scanned it).

Edit: Amine Hajyoussef pointed you in the right direction with `document.DocumentNode.Innerhtml`, though note that you'll need to change the return type of the function as well.